# Запустить скрипт написанный на Python 3.* из под Python 2.*

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

1. Запустить Python 3.х из под питона 2.х (или IronPython)
2. Запустить выполнение скрипта написанного на Python 3.x
3. По возможности получить выходные данные и вернуть их в Python 2.x

P.S. И есть ли возможность поместить тело скрипта для Py3  в тело Py2 ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на компьютере установлен `python3`, то можно, например, через модуль [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) запустить интерпертатор с скриптом.

Пример запуска интерпретатора питона. `sys.executable` -- полный путь до интерпретатора, можно заменить, например на строку "С:\Python3\python.exe", который выполняет скрипт `<script>.py`. Скрипт `<script>.py` что-то пишет консоль, мы это ловим и у себя в консоль пишем:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

with Popen([sys.executable, '-u', '<script>.py'], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: а можно подробнее ваш вариант узнать?

Comment: Обновил ответ кодом

Comment: Да, спасибо! То что нужно! А есть возможность в теле основного кода спрятать  строки для  отправки  в другой python? Т.е. не создавать дополнительный  '<script>.py'

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите передавать аргументы (`sys.argv`) запускаемому скрипту?

Comment: В моём случае допустим идёт тело  скрипта для Py2.*

PY=r'C:\python3\python.exe'
scr=r'C:\Users\Man\Desctop\test.py'    (скрипт для Py3.*)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Popen([PY, '-u', SCR], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
        for line in process.stdout:
            print(line, end='')

И вот  как раз все что содержится в "SCR" Хотелось быть тут и оставить, не вызывая дополнительного запуска файла

Comment: Можно было бы импортировать файл, но из-за различий между python2 и python3 он может и не запуститься